# Selenium printing with chrome, keeps showing a save popup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need some automated script that will print a page. This script has to run on Chrome, as FF does not give me a decent output for this printing task. I tried several things, but for some reason it still requeires a filename, and it ignores what I use for both savefile.default_directory and download.default_directory setting. This is the script I am currently working on (needless to say, I tried removing and adding parts, tried setting the TMP_DIR to my acctual default download, and so on).

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
def main():
    TMP_DIR = "F:/Downloads"
    printer = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
    print_settings = {
            "recentDestinations": [{
                "id": printer,
                "origin": "local",
                "account": "",
            }],
            "selectedDestinationId": printer,
            "version": 2,
            "isHeaderFooterEnabled": False,
            "isLandscapeEnabled": True
        }
    
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
    # options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument('--enable-print-browser')
    options.add_argument("--kiosk")
    options.add_argument("--kiosk-printing")
    options.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
    options.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");

    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState": json.dumps(print_settings),
        "savefile.default_directory": TMP_DIR,  # Change default directory for downloads
        "download.default_directory": TMP_DIR,  # Change default directory for downloads
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,  # To auto download the file
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads": 1,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": True
    })

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/97252/Downloads/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe", 
                    chrome_options=options)
    
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    driver.execute_script("window.print();")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Using chrome / chromedriver 121.0.6167.184
Python 3.9.13
selenium==3.11.0

is there anything else I can do to force the download? Bonus if I can set the filename, however at this point I'll settle for anything.

Comment: I cleaned up the script and it made me miss an important part: I am putting a time.sleep(10) at the end of the script, to give the printing a chance to happen.

Comment: Do you want to A) print the page or do you want to B) save a screenshot that you then can print? If a screenshot, you then at an actual visual representation of the viewport. With printing a PDF directly you retain texts as it converts the HTML to PDF, yet you lose the visual representation.

Comment: I need to run the print function. A screenshot won't do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Found a strange solution, that I cannot say I like.
To prevent the dialog, chrome needs to simulate a mobile. Why? I have no idea, but it works. Apply the following fixes:

```
    print_settings = {
        "recentDestinations": [{
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }],
        "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
        "version": 2,
        "isHeaderFooterEnabled": False,
        "mediaSize": { # for some reason, mobile printing assumes A5 papers.
            "height_microns": 297000,
            "name": "ISO_A4",
            "width_microns": 210000,
            "custom_display_name": "A4"
        },
        "customMargins": {},
        "marginsType": 2,
        "scaling": 175,
        "scalingType": 3,
        "scalingTypePdf": 3,
        "isCssBackgroundEnabled": True
    }

    mobile_emulation = {
        "deviceMetrics": { "width": 1024, "height": 600, "pixelRatio": 1.41 },
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19",
        "clientHints": {"platform": "Android", "mobile": True} 
   }
    options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the solution above works well, it has the tendancy not to allways work. I suggest using access to Chrome developer tools to send a print to pdf note:

```
def send_to_devtools(driver, command, params=None):
    # pylint: disable=protected-access
    if params is None:
        params = {}
    resource = "/session/%s/chromium/send_command_and_get_result" % driver.session_id
    url = driver.command_executor._url + resource
    body = json.dumps({"cmd": command, "params": params})
    resp = driver.command_executor._request("POST", url, body)
    return resp.get("value")

def export_pdf(driver):
    command = "Page.printToPDF"
    params = {"format": "A4"}
    result = send_to_devtools(driver, command, params)
    data = result.get("data")
    return data

.
.
.

        pdf_data = export_pdf(driver)
        with open(outfile, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(pdf_data))
```